# Add a leading comment to a compiled typescript file

Tags: typescript, comments, tsconfig

Im kind of new to typescript.
I'm searching for a method to tell typescript to add a leading comment at the top of a compiled file.

So e.g., I want

`foo.ts`

```
export class Bar {}
```

to get compiled to

`foo.js`

```
/*-----This is a compiled typescript file, see ... for more-----*/
export class Bar {}
```

Is there an option for that, or how could i solve this ?

Comment: use tsdoc format